# Should http requests be in the constructor or in a static function?

Tags: java, coding-standards, http

Which is conventional? For example, this is in the constructor:

```
public class Foo {
...
    public Foo(...) {
        // http requests
    }
...
}
```

and this is in the static method:

```
public class Foo {
...
    public Foo(...) {
        ...
    }

    public static Foo get(...) {
        // http requests
        return Foo(...);
    }
...
}
```

Are there any advantages/disadvantages to either one? (threading, speed?)

Comment: It depends entirely on what Foo does and how it's used. Could you provide some more details?

Comment: Why not using an object function ? Provide more details for `Foo` please.

Comment: @Spotted What do you mean by object function?

Comment: @Ixrec In my case, Foo simply consumes the CRUD parts of my API. It's just a wrapper.

Comment: @umopaplsdn I mean a non-static function inside `Foo`.

Comment: @Spotted Do you mean construct the object, then have the function override the object? Or just make the same function non-static? If the second, then you'd have to allocate memory to create the object whenever you wanted to call it, and the syntax would be longer (`(new Foo()).get(...);` instead of `Foo.get(...);`).

Answer (score 4):

There is a [general consensus](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1371369) that a constructor *shouldn't* ever throw an exception in Java. It can cause a mess with trying to recover from the `new`.  You can, but its one of those "try to avoid it if it can be done in a sensible way."

To that extent, the static Builder (that you call `get(...)`) is probably a better approach to follow. That allows you to properly build and dispose/close the resources for invoking http and handle the exceptions (what if this request fails? or that next one?)

With a Builder approach, one should consider making the constructor private so that you can guarantee that the state of `Foo` is properly constructed by the `get(...)` method, if it is constructed at all.

For threading and speed? There is really no difference. It is entirely an issue of making sure that exceptions are thrown in a non-surprising circumstance and any resources (the web requests) are properly closed in the event something goes wrong.

Comment: How do you detect an invalid constructor call?  Do you just get a null object back?

Comment: @RobertHarvey you don't get *anything* back because you threw an exception. Completely different path through the code.

Comment: But if you're not supposed to throw exceptions in constructors...

Comment: Then you should instead have a Builder or Factory that does the work, and then invokes a private or otherwise publically inaccessible constructor. The Builder or Factory could call the appropriate methods and throw an exception. This becomes an important distinction when you get subclasses that call `super()` and find an exception coming back up that they then have to say "well, guess that's it" and continue throwing the exception up the stack. If they *didn't*, it would mean that you have a partially constructed object (super didn't do its job) and that leads to all sorts of unfun bugs.

Comment: The main thing here is that the http requests (say, multiple requests for JSON obejcts that are going to be deseralzed with the custom builder here) are things that can fail. It could be a File load or Database request (that's what row mappers are for if you are going down that route)... those are things that you'd rather avoid doing in a constructor to avoid that surprising exception.